# Ubuntu Server in VirtualBox -- why do I have to reinstall after shutdown?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

After I "send a shutdown signal", I find I have to reinstall Ubuntu Server inside VirtualBox. This doesn't seem right. I should simply have to restart an installed version of Ubuntu Server.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry for not being explicit enough. I have a Mac OS X host, with Ubuntu Server in a VirtualBox guest. When I close the Ubuntu Server guest, I get the usual 3 options: "Save State", "Send Shutdown Signal", "Power Off Machine." I thought if I did "Send Shutdown Signal", my guest OS would shut down, and I would be able to easily restart it in future. Instead, the next time I try to revive my guest OS, I find I have to reinstall the entire damn thing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not telling us the rest of the story is wrong, for one thing. Why are you reinstalling?

Comment: Please explain what you've done in detail. What is the host OS? How did you install exactly? Have you left the installation ISO attached to the VM?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback people, I have updated my question with more detail.

Comment: You ask your VM to shut down from within it's OS, or risk corrupting your VHD. Doing the equivalent of pulling the power plug from the outside has the usual results.

Comment: I just tried "sudo shutdown -h 0", and it shut down itself. But when I powered it up again, I was forced to reinstall it. Why? Oh why?

Comment: Are there any error messages or anything that indicated something failed and you need to reinstall? Have you checked @terdon comment about "Did you left the ISO attached to the VM" and to add "Is the VM first-boot device is the ISO?" (which then creates the loop)

Comment: @Darius -- brilliant! you're right... I didn't fully comprehend what terdon was implying... this must be it, I've been leaving the ISO attached, and have the boot order set to CD Drive first... so obviously this is what was happening! ... thanks!!!!! I wish I could give you points for the right answer... this is the right answer folks!

Comment: Heh! Yep, that would do it...

Answer (score 0):

You can "import" servers into VirtualBox or save a particular state of a virtual machine and revert back to that state using "snapshots". You can save your VMs using VirtualBox Manager.

If you don't save it, then the "virtual" machine is lost when you turn it off.

Comment: The problem for me is that I want to shutdown my guest OS, make some changes to the network settings of VirtualBox and then restart the guest OS. (I'm trying to SSH into the guest from the host, and finding that hard to do, hence the changes to the settings.)

Comment: Can you save the state before shutting it down? You can also take snapshots with various settings and revert back to them to test the various network settings.

Comment: Many settings are greyed out. Yes, it helps that I can take snapshots. But I'm unable to fiddle around with most settings.